# Current image slider for rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to find an image slider to use with Rails 5.  I have found a few gem's but they are all quite old and require older versions of rails.  Does anyone know of a good image slider I can use?

I tried jssorslider but it hasn't been updated in a few years and required rails 3, there is owlcarousel which hasn't been updated in three years. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about bootstrap carousel you wouldn't have to install extra gems. You can read more about it on the bootstrap page: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/carousel/

And on W3Schools: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Rails gem bxSlider https://github.com/manfe/bxslider-rails